# Writing a JSON string from Java to Excel in a formatted way

Tags: java, json, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to write a JSON in string format to an excel file in Java. I know how to write to the file but I can't figure out how to format it.

For example if I wanted to write this:

{'data':[{'id':1,'name':'Eredivisie','active':true}]}

To an excel file how could I implement it so each value appears in its own separate cell? Like this: [Screenshot of sample excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lq6q.png)

I have done research but can't find a simple answer. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how is this question related to vba?

Comment: Have a look at the CSV file format.

Comment: other than CSV you could write directly in Excel format with [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org) even though it might be overkill

Answer (score 0):

The CSV (comma separated values) file format is a good choice.

So you would just output text to a file, separating each value with a comma. E.G:

```
ID,Name,Active
1,Eredivisie,true
...etc
```

Depending on your data (if it contains any commas), you may have to choose a different character to separate the values. Good job that in excel you can specify which character you are using.

Comment: I understand the question to be one of converting some JSON data into a format that is displayable in Excel.

Comment: As per my understanding OP's question is how to write the data in JSON to and Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the JSON as simple POJO object and then format the POJO object as string to create a CSV format.

The code will look some thing like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Data> dataList = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);

StringBuilder csvFormattedText = new StringBuilder("id, name, active");

forEach (Data data : dataList) {
    scvFormattedText.append(data.getId()).append(", ")
       .append(data.getName)
       .append(", ")
       .append(data.getActiveStatus())
       .append("\n");
}

File csvFile = new File("fromJSON.csv");
try ( PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(csvFile)) {
  out.println(csvFormattedText.toString());
}
```

Here Data is the POJO class which is created based on the fields in JSON.
In this way, you can convert the JSON to CSV file and thus it can be opened using excel.

If you dont like this approach, you may have to use libraries like `Apache POI` to convert JSON to xls. You have to follow same process, only difference it POI help you to set the values in each cell of the spreadsheet.

Further reading on POI library: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do something more just pull the json and then apply them to write in excel ,create new row then create new 4 cells in each object

```
  JSONObject json=new JSONObject("{\"data\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Eredivisie\",\"active\":true}]}

    JSONObject data=new json.getJSONObject("data"));
    cell1.setCellStringValue(data.getString("id"));
    cell2.setCellStringValue(data.getString("name"));
    cell3.setCellStringValue(data.getString("Eredivisie"));
    cell4.setCellStringValue(data.getString("active"));
```